# Instances api insert method was broken, can not create instance, neither the try it out

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

Instances api insert method was broken, can not create instance, neither the try it out .

return 400 code, detail was: machinetypes must be valid url

Answer (score 0):

'machineType' has to be a fully-qualified URL of the machine type resource to use for the instance. Example:

"machineType" : "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/`<your project ID>`/zones/us-central1-a/machineTypes/n1-standard-1"